# how to use Lame library in android to convert .Pcm file to Mp3

Tags: android, android-ndk, mp3, pcm, lame

I am using [Lame](https://lame.sourceforge.net/download.php) library to convert pcm file to mp3 in android.
using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34812738/how-to-add-lame-3-99-5-to-android-studio-using-ndk) link I compiled it and every thing is ok.

but I don't know how to use this library to convert .Pcm file to .Mp3 in android studio.

any sample code or any hint would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is an example: https://github.com/intervigilium/Lame4Android/blob/master/src/com/intervigil/lame/Main.java
It seems that you need to do a Lame object and `onActivityResult` do the conversion of the file or see this as a possible duplicated question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34322713/6848782

Comment: i think i have to build the project but there is no build option in build menu . could you help me how I can build it ? com.intervigil.wave.WaveReader is not in the project and I don't know how to add it and where it is !?

Comment: @unosbaghaii In the github code you have it here https://github.com/intervigilium/libwave/tree/master/src/com/intervigil/wave and all the code inside wave folder is that you need. The best way I recommend you is to add all this github project as a library. If you don't know how I recommend you to find another way in the possible duplicated  answer in stackoverflow site that I mentioned to you