# Covert video file to audio file in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, audio, xamarin.forms, file-conversion

I am trying to create an app that allows a user to download the audio of youtube videos in Xamarin.Forms. I can download the video using 'VideoLibrary' and convert it to an mp3 using 'MediaToolkit' in a C# Console Application without any errors.

```
static void DownloadAudio(string videoUrl, string saveDir)
{
    YouTube youtube = YouTube.Default;
    Video vid = youtube.GetVideo(videoUrl);
    File.WriteAllBytes(saveDir + vid.FullName, vid.GetBytes());

    string originalFile = saveDir + vid.FullName;
    var inputFile = new MediaToolkit.Model.MediaFile { Filename = saveDir + vid.FullName };
    var outputFile = new MediaToolkit.Model.MediaFile { Filename = $"{saveDir + vid.FullName}.mp3" };

    using (var engine = new MediaToolkit.Engine())
    {
        engine.GetMetadata(inputFile);

        engine.Convert(inputFile, outputFile);
        if (File.Exists(originalFile))
        {
            File.Delete(originalFile);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that this won't work in Xamarin. Only the portable version of the nuget package can be installed which doesn't contain definitions for `Engine` or `MediaFile`.

Furthermore, not all videos download as `.mp4`, some download as `.webm`. I need the output files to be both `.mp3` and `.mp4`.

How can I convert the video files into audio files in Xamarin.Forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not available from a PCL, you could opt to platform dependencies. Basically you create an interface for the functionality you need, implement the classes in your platform specific projects and export them with the [`DependencyAttribute`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.DependencyAttribute/). From your PCL you can now obtain an instance with the `DependencyService` (see [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/) and [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UsingDependencyService/)).

The interface could look like the following

```
public interface IMediaHelper
{
    void ConvertToMp3(string fullFileName);
}
```

and the implementation (in your iOS and Android projects - use a SharedProject to avoid code duplication)

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(MediaHelper))]

public class MediaHelper
{
    public void ConvertToMp3(string fullFileName)
    {
        var infile = new MediaToolkit.Model.MediaFile { Filename = fullFileName;
        var outfile = new MediaToolkit.Model.MediaFile { Filename = $"{fullFileName}.mp3" };

        using (var engine = new MediaToolkit.Engine())
        {
            engine.GetMetadata(infile);

            engine.Convert(infile, outfile);
            if (File.Exists(fullFileName))
            {
                File.Delete(fullFileName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Consequently your client code would be

```
void DownloadAudio(string videoUrl, string saveDir)
{
    YouTube youtube = YouTube.Default;
    Video vid = youtube.GetVideo(videoUrl);

    var fullFileName = Path.Combine(saveDir, vid.FullName);

    File.WriteAllBytes(fullFileName, vid.GetBytes());

    var mediaHelper = DependencyService.Get<IMediaHelper>();
    mediaHelper.ConvertToMp3(fullFileName);
}
```

**Please Note:** I have replaced the manual concatenation of the path and the file with the call to `Path.Combine`, which handles cases in which the path already comes with the path separator. Furthermore it handles the different platforms for you.

### Without MediaToolkit

Obviously MediaToolkit won't work for Android (at least), hence you'll have to go the same way - with the platform dependencies - and implement what you need with what you've got out-of-the-box. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35694942/2249175) on how to extract PCM data from a video and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34322713/2249175) on how to convert PCM to MP3 - just to give you an idea.

**Please note**

> [...] if you want to encode/decode a mp3 file you may have to pay license/patent fees.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15901543/2249175)

Comment: This does make sense, but how would I use it to get around this error: 
`Could not install package 'MediaToolkit 1.1.0.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v8.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.`

Comment: @MuhammadKhan - unfortunately it does not seem to support android.

Comment: The `mp4` to `PCM` to `mp3` workaround is all in java, how can I do use it in Xamarin.Forms (C#)?

Comment: Xamarin.Android wraps the whole Java API, under Android you should be able to use the functions. See the Xamarin docs to see the class and function names, since accessor methods are translated to properties.