# Get system audio stream

Tags: android, ios, audio, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to find a solution to return the current system audio stream in Xamarin.Forms (for iOS and Android).

As example: There is a new feature from Shazam since iOS14 where you can not record the microphone input but the system audio input, like a running Spotify song.

I just want that as a stream to filter it through Fast Fourier Transform and send it to a microcontroller for some sound reactive LED effects.

Could not find an extension or Nuget package yet, do you know any or maybe some working solution ?

Best regards
nflug

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the audio stream from the videos or some mp3 files and so on?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT yes correct. Everything that is currently running in the background, but for now just the audio would be perfect.

Comment: How about convert the videos into audio? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47739793/covert-video-file-to-audio-file-in-xamarin-forms

Comment: This is not my question @WendyZang-MSFT I don't want to play any audio or video and get the stream. What I want is to get the source or running stream from any other apps audio, as example as I said like a currently running Spotify song.

Comment: If you want to get the audio from the other app, you need the other app give you the permission and open a interface. So that you could get the other apps audio.

Comment: Yes you are right. I tested the new shazam widget again and it also works over the microphone, so my question is solved, not possible only over the microphone or if you play your own song or video in the app.